# Make blank page after Table of Contents empty/plain

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, double-sided

I am preparing a document using the twoside class option.
The end of the Table of Contents falls such that an blank page is inserted so that the following section (List of Figures FWIW) falls on an odd page.
However, the blank page has headers (using `fancyhdr`), which I believe will look odd with no content, on a verso page, with the start of the List of Figures on the recto.

How can I make this page empty, or plain (i.e. with only a page number)?

I have tried using `\thispagestyle{plain}`, but it does not affect pages with the TOC.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually

```
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\begingroup
  \pagestyle{empty}%
  \cleardoublepage
\endgroup
\listoffigures
```

does the trick (the manual version). Some classes have options for the page style of such pages:

- Class `memoir` uses page style `cleared`. By default, it is defined using page style empty:

  ```
  \aliaspagestyle{cleared}{empty}
  ```

  But it can be changed to `plain`, `fancyplain` or whatever, e.g.:

  ```
  \aliaspagestyle{cleared}{plain}
  ```
- KOMAScript has an option `cleardoublepage`, which gets the page style as argument, e.g.:

  ```
  cleardoublepage=plain
  ```
- With other classes, `\cleardoublepage` can be redefined:

  ```
  \newcommand*{\OriginalClearDoublePage}{}
  \let\OriginalClearDoublePage\cleardoublepage
  \renewcommand*{\cleardoublepage}{%
    \clearpage
    \begingroup
      \pagestyle{plain}%
      \OriginalClearDoublePage
    \endgroup
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks, your manual solution works well. I'd be interested to know how it works - please could you explain?

Comment: @DaveW There is not much to explain. `\clearpage` ends the previous stuff. Then we are at the start of a new page, either odd or even. In the latter case `\cleardoublepage` adds the empty page with the page style specified before. The page style change is kept local by the group. (Therefore I have updated the answer to `\pagestyle`).